# Can I map an EnumSet to a series of boolean columns automatically using Hibernate Annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, data-mapping

I have an EnumSet that I thought it would be good to map into a series of boolean columns.  This will make it easy to inspect using SQL tools and also resilient to changes to the available enum values.  However, I don't really want to hand-write all the getters and setters for this.

Does anyone have a clever solution using some kind of hibernate metadata to split this object into a bunch of properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, for an enum like:

```
public enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE; }
```

you would have 3 true/false columns in a database, one for each possible enum value. Then an `EnumSet` containing, say, RED and BLUE, should be mapped to:

```
RED    GREEN    BLUE
true   false    true
```

If that's the case, the only way I know of is to write your own implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`. It's a pretty straight-forward task, with some examples available on Hibernate site and, for instance, [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/4857635/Advanced-Hibernate).

**Edit**: I just realized things would have to be somewhat more complex. If you wish to have one Hibernate type mapping for all possible `EnumSet` in your application, you will have to do the following:

1. Use `org.hibernate.usertype.ParameterizedType` and make user type parameterizable by an enum class.
2. Depending on values of enum class, determine how many and what columns to read/write.
3. Instantiate the type each time an `EnumSet` is used.
4. Consider the possibility of mapping multiple sets in one table, as well as how adding a new enum value will influence workings of existing type.

This could easily amount to full day's work, but seems quite doable. Hope you figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks ... I did it by hand but you provided what is probably the only solution.